# How do I concatenate two files and write the result back to one of the original files

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, cat, head

I am trying to get the first 4 lines from `somefile`, concatenate them with the contents of `someotherfile` and output it to `somefile`.

```
head -4 /somefile | cat - /someotherfile > /somefile
```

When I do this the contents of `someotherfile` ends up in `somefile`, but not the first 4 lines. If I output to a totally different file then it works great.

Obviously there is an issue with trying to write to the same file I am reading from. What would be the simplest way to accomplish this task?

I am attempting to do this on RedHat Enterprise 6, bash shell.

Comment: `head -4 /somefile | cat - /someotherfile > /yetanotherfile && mv /yetanotherfile /somefile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save `head` output to temporary variable, like this:

```
HEAD="$(head -4 some file)"
(echo "$HEAD"; cat someotherfile) >some file
```

Or you can remove all lines starting from 5th and append content of another file to the end:

```
sed -i '5,$d' somefile
cat someotherfile >>somefile
```

Comment: Thanks Slava. I went with your second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the problem:

"Obviously there is an issue with trying to write to the same file I am reading from."

Use another file to write to and when done move it to the original file overwriting it. Or use some kind of tooling to read the original file in memory first before writing to it, but I am not sure if bash has something like that.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you want to *edit* the file `somefile` as follows: delete everything after its fourth line, and append the file `someotherfile`.

You can use `ed`, the standard editor!

```
ed -s somefile < <(printf '%s\n' '5,$d' 'r someotherfile' 'wq') &> /dev/null
```

- `5,$d` tells `ed` to delete everything from the fifth line until the end of the file (the `&>/dev/null` is here to not see any of `ed`'s complaints in case the file `somefile` has less than 4 lines).
- `r someotherfile` will insert the file `someotherfile`.
- `wq` is how you say *kthxbye (and save)* to `ed`.

Comment: This didn't work for some reason. There was no error, but after I ran it "somefile" was still the same as before. I did like that this was a one-line solution.

Comment: @irrational: sorry it didn't work. Might be because of a slight detail on how RH's `ed` work. Try by hand: `ed somefile`. Then, from within `ed` try the commands: `5,$d`, `r someotherfile` and `wq` and see where `ed` complains. Maybe the last `wq` should be `w` and then `q`. From your experience like this, you'll see how to adapt the line I gave to your case.